# Can i set profile picture directly from webpage on facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

Using javascript SDK can i change profile picture on my facebook directly with out uploading it on timeline? Or there is no way to update profile pic directly?

Comment: i believe you can not do this operation . your can read about it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/
Which says on  Updating
You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Comment: You are correct. It is not possible to do direct